# Classification problem of equivariant vector bundles on affine space

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, vector-bundles

We work over $\mathbb{C}$.  Let $\mathfrak{k}$ be a Lie algebra, and let $V,W$ be finite-dimensional $\mathfrak{k}$-modules.  Consider the $\mathfrak{k}$-algebra $A:=S^\bullet V$.  Write $\mathfrak{m}$ for the maximal ideal at $0\in V^*$, a $\mathfrak{k}$-module.

Let $M$ be a $\mathfrak{k}$-equivariant, free $A$-module with $M/\mathfrak{m}M\cong W$ as $\mathfrak{k}$-modules.  Being $\mathfrak{k}$-equivariant means that $\mathfrak{k}$ acts on $M$ such that for $m\in M$, $a\in A$, and $x\in\mathfrak{k}$ we have
$$
x(am)=x(a)m+ax(m).
$$
Under what conditions on $V$ and $W$ can we conclude that $M$ is in fact globally trivial, i.e. that $M\cong W\otimes A$ as $\mathfrak{k}$-modules?  I assume there must be a nice cohomology group that classifies the set of all such $M$ up to isomorphism, and that someone has studied it before; does anyone have a reference?  Obviously if $\mathfrak{k}$ is reductive then it is true, but I'm working with nonreductive Lie algebras so this doesn't help me.

Thanks for any help!